# Chef cookbook_file run script if updated

Tags: chef-infra

Does anyone know if it is possible to make a script resource dependent on weather or not a cookbook_file was updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependent upon, no.  But you can setup a notification so that one triggers the other.

```rb
cookbook_file 'something'

script 'myscript' do
  ....
  action :nothing
  subscribes :run, 'cookbook_file[something]' #, :immediately
end
```

If you uncomment the `immediately` it will run right after the cookbook_file updates, if you leave it commented (or remove it) then it will run at the end of the chef run.

Actually, on second thought, you could potentially do it, but it would be somewhat ugly.  **Untested**

```rb
r = cookbook_file 'my_file'

script 'myscript' do
  command lazy{r.updated ? "your command" : "no-op"}
end
```

however, your script resource would "execute" every chef run, so you lose the idempotence.

Comment: I see no benefit in the second approach. The first one is what I would use (an alternative would to have the `notifies` in the `cookbook_file`, instead of the `script` subscribing to it).

Comment: @StephenKing I couldn't agree more.  Notifications are the way to go, but if there were some reason that a notification isn't an option, then I think the second approach could work, but I'd still avoid it if at all possible.